# Cloud hosting of Multiple Choice Test

Tags: cloud-deploy

I am looking to create a very simple quiz but one with a lot of equations.  It needs to be hosted in the cloud and students taking said quiz should not need and Wolfram licenses. This seems a straightforward goal but I've not found any tutorial or instructions on line. Could someone give me a pointer?

Comment: Check this out: [Online multiple choice quiz using FormPage](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1360762). Also check out [AskFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AskFunction.html)